# Linked list trouble in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to add a node to head, but the head is nil. Any idea what is going on?

[I have this picture of the debug process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J17X.png)

[Note that it is an implementation of a linked list with size, don't let that confuse you!]

Node.h

```
//literally contains no other code and the .m file is empty, all I want
//is a pointer to the next object
@interface Node : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak, readwrite) Node *next;
@end
```

NList.m -- Omitted .h because I think it should be fine

```
@interface NList()
@property (weak, nonatomic, readwrite) Node *head;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger size;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger num_nodes;
@end

...


- (id) initWithSize:(NSInteger)size {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.head = nil;
        self.size = size;
        self.num_nodes = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)add:(NSObject *)node {
    Node *newNode = [[Node alloc] init];
    if (self.head){
        newNode.next = self.head;
        self.head = newNode;
    }
    else{
        self.head = newNode;
    }
    self.num_nodes++;
}
```

test file

```
- (void)testAdd
{
    NList *testList = [[NList alloc] initWithSize:2];
    NSObject *testNodeOne =  @1;
    [testList add:(testNodeOne)];
    XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head);
    NSObject *testNodeTwo =  @3;

    [testList add:testNodeTwo];
    XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head);
    //XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head.next);

}
```

Comment: @Nighthawk441 his properties say `weak`, he must be

Comment: Change your `weak` properties to `strong`. Otherwise there is nothing keeping a reference to each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are the properties for your nodes weak? Based on what you showed here they should be strong. The list itself should retain the root node (head), and each node in the list should retain the next node, otherwise nothing else will retain those objects.

Also, as a side note, looking at your properties I think you have confused the default when looking at `readwrite` vs `readonly`. `readwrite` is the default and does not need to be specified explicitly. `readonly` needs to be specified explicitly for any properties that should not have a mutator. You seem to have this backwards in your properties.

Comment: Okay, I have a question. From what I understood a strong pointer wasn't needed because a strong pointer to the object already existed somewhere else. What I was creating was pointer number two for the objects in the linked list, just so that they can be accessed by the linked list

Comment: What gave you that idea? It would exist if you made one but there is only one pointer to each node and right now they are all weak. In this context you need a strong pointer. The list **should** retain/own the root node, and each node **should** retain/own the next node.

Comment: Oh. Makes sense!! So my head is there now, but the assert still fails. Mind taking a look at this picture and trying to make sense of it? http://i.imgur.com/7NXicDs.png

Comment: Did you change the `head` property to be `(strong, nonatomic)`? This looks like it should work.

Comment: in the .h I have atproperty (strong, readonly, nonatomic) Node *head;
 .. in the .m  I have atproperty (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) Node *head;

Comment: You should not be declaring the property twice. Remove one of them.